# How do I enable only mods from a specific collection?

Tags: garrys-mod

I would like to have a LAN party with my brother with only a few choice mods that I picked out in Garry's Mod. I don't want my brother to have to download all the other mods I have installed for myself every time he joins my LAN party. What do I do?

P.S. I'm using the latest version of Garry's Mod (I assume that's 13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** make a collection of certain mods you only want to disable or enable. But here is what you can do:

1. Your brother can install the mods that you and him want to use in the LAN server
2. He goes to `Settings`, `Multiplayer`, and change `Allow all custom content from a server` to download only maps or nothing at all.

Hope this helps!